# jest - testing mobx store @action TypeError: is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, mobx

I have the following store:

```
import { observable, action } from "mobx";

class UiStore {
  @observable string;

  constructor() {
    this.string = "My string";
  }

  @action
  setString = value => {
    this.string = value;
  };
}

export default UiStore;
```

And a simple test I am running with jest:

```
import UiStore from "./UiStore";

describe("uiStore", () => {
  it("setString sets string to the passed value", () => {
    const uiStore = new UiStore();
    uiStore.setString("blah");
    expect(uiStore.string).toBe("blah");
  });
});
```

But I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: uiStore.setString is not a function

When I remove the `@action` decorator, the test will pass. But according to the [mobx docs](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/action.html), the `@action` decorator significantly increases performance when the functions are modifying state. Does anybody know of a way to test mobx @actions?

Comment: The strange thing here is that it runs fine in my browser, the decorated class field properties method only fails during the test run.

Comment: I figured it out. I was experiencing this error in my test suite but not in browser due to separate babel configs for each. Please refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49621490/569061) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Not using a arrow function solves this problem:

```
import { observable, action } from "mobx";

class UiStore {
  @observable string;

  constructor() {
    this.string = "My string";
  }

  @action
  setString(value) {
    this.string = value;
  }
}

export default UiStore;
```

No idea why though...

Comment: Oh... decorators work with class methods. What you had before was a class field (property, or w.e. its called these days)

Comment: `setString = value => { this.string = value; };` in the code in your question will result in a bound function. You might want `@action.bound setString(value) { this.string = value; }`

Answer (score 0):

In order for *decorators* to work with *class field methods* you must ensure that when using the `transform-decorators-legacy` and `transform-class-properties` plugins that you put them in the right order in your `.babelrc`, for example:

**Incorrect ✖**

```
"plugins": [
  "transform-class-properties",
  "transform-decorator-legacy",
]
```

**Correct ✔**

```
"plugins": [
  "transform-decorator-legacy",
  "transform-class-properties",      
]
```

Alternatively you may use the `@action.bound` decorator on a class method, which will bind it as if it was a class field method, as Miha suggested in his answer.